# Is it possible to solve this system of equalities?

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, systems-of-equations, linear-programming

First, I will say that In this system, I know the actual value of A,B,C,D,E,F.  I want to solve for G,H,I,J,K,L.  I know that there *is* a solution of whole numbers.  And I know the following:

> A = G+H
>
> B = I+J
>
> C = K+L
>
> D = G+H+I+J+K+L
>
> E = G+I+K
>
> F = H+J+L

So, if I know the integer values of ABCDEF, is it possible to solve for GHIJKL?

Just to be clear, A,B,C,D,E, and F all have different integer values.  But this isn't a specific situation, so I am trying to learn how to solve it *in general*

Comment: $A+B+C=D=E+F$ for solutions to exist at all, and in that case two of the equations are redundant.

Comment: It is the case that A+B+C=D=E+F.
I simply posted all the information I knew :/

They are not redundant though... E and F have different integer values than A and B (individually)

Comment: Then choose some arbitrary $\,G,I\,$ (for example), and solve for the remaining unknowns. `They are not redundant though` They *are* redundant, because you can derive equations $\,C=\ldots\,$ and $\,F=\ldots\,$ (for example) from the other four, as long as $\,A+B+C=D=E+F\,$ is satisfied.

Comment: Ah ok, as I was posting that I realized that it was likely you were correct when you were saying that they were redundant, so my bad there.  As for choosing an arbitrary G,I - I am not sure I understand.  After *doing that* it seems to me that finding the specific solution I am looking for is not possible because there are infinite solutions ?

Comment: There are infinitely many solutions (under the additional constraints, otherwise there are none). You could also note that if $\,G,H,I,J,K,L\,$ is a solution, then so is $\,G+1,H-1,I-1,J+1,K,L\,$, and $\,G+2,H-2,I-2,J+2,K,L\,$, and $\ldots$

Comment: yikes... that's unfortunate.  maybe I can still make use out of this though.  Well, thank you for your help.